# Python insert element based on condition

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a list where based on a condition, an element may or may not exist. For example, if it's true, the list is `[1, 2, 3]`, and otherwise, it's `[1, 3]`. Currently, what I could do is either initialize the list and call `.insert` or `.append` the elements individually, or alternatively, I could do something like `[1] + ([2] if condition else []) + [3]`, but that's ugly.

I was wondering if there was some sort of syntax like `[1, 2 if condition, 3]` for example, but I can't seem to find anything of that sort. Is there a similar syntax to this?

**EDIT** My list isn't `[1, 2, 3]`. I want a general solution for any type of object because I'm not even working with numbers (these are WTForms validators)

Answer (score 7):

I'm also used to doing this in Perl with a pattern like:

```perl
my @arr = (1, (condition? (2) : ()), 3);
```

In Python you can get somewhat close to this with a solution that's pretty close to what you have with the list `+`, but uses `*` unpacking to avoid a lot of the other arrays:

```py
arr = [1, *((2,) if condition else ()), 3]
```

Could clean that up a little with a helper that yields the value if the condition is true.

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def cond(val: T, ok: bool) -> Iterable[T]:
    if ok:
        yield val

arr = [1, *cond(2, condition), 3]
```

This has the downside of not short circuiting though, so if the creation of the used value is expensive you might want to provide a function instead of a value to be called and returned when the condition is true.

Yet another option could be to use a sentinel value and filter for it when constructing the list. Can combine this with a helper to do the filtering.

```py
class _Ignore: pass
IGNORE = _Ignore()

def cond_list(*elements: Union[T, _Ignore]) -> list[T]:
    return [e for e in elements if not isinstance(e, _Ignore)]


arr = cond_list(1, 2 if condition else IGNORE, 3)
```

If you want to stay flexible for the resulting container type you could choose to return an iterable which you can pass to a container constructor:

```py
def cond_iter(*elements: Union[T, _Ignore]) -> Iterable[T]:
    yield from (e for e in elements if not isinstance(e, _Ignore))


arr = set(cond_iter(1, 2 if condition else IGNORE, 3))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a list with conditions and use list comprehension:

```
condition = [True, False, True, True, False]
[i for i in range(len(condition)) if condition[i]]
```

Comment: Huh, cool solution. I'd probably still prefer just building the list with inserts or appends since I'm trying to improve readability and make it absolutely clear what I'm doing, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you have a list of contidions for all  elements you could to this:

```
elems = ['a', 'b', 'c']
conditions = [True, False, True]

lst = [item for item, condition in zip(elems, conditions) if condition]
print(lst)
```

that could also be done using [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=compress#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress

elems = ['a', 'b', 'c']
conditions = [True, False, True]
lst = list(compress(elems, conditions))
```

---

or you generate your list and remove the element afterwards:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if condition:
    lst.remove('b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

`[i for i in range(1,4) if i!=2]`

UPDATE: based on nice answer above.

Making condition a function instead of a list will generalize it.

```
def condition(x):
    if(x==2):
        return False
    else:
        return True

[i for i in range(1,4) if condition(i)]
```

Comment: This works for my example but I'm trying to get a general solution and also my example is literally just for demonstration.

Comment: This was a good question.  The function instead of list may offer some more generality.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to generate the list with a generator like:

```
def generate(condition: bool, value: int):
  yield 1
  if condition:
    yield value
  yield 3
l = list(generate(True, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the splat/unpacking operator to expand an element either to the object you want to add or to nothing. Try changing the condition from True to False to check the results.

```py
class FirstClass:
  x = 5
  
class SecondClass:
  y = 10


possible_object = (SecondClass().y,) if True else ()
l = [
    FirstClass().x,
    *possible_object,
    FirstClass().x,
    *possible_object,
]
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a variation of this answer before, but maybe this makes it more readable, like you wanted?

```
def is_not_dog(item):
    return item != "dog"

items = ["cat", "dog", "horse", "snail"]

not_dog = [i for i in items if is_not_dog(i)]
not_dog
```

> ['cat', 'horse', 'snail']

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt using filter():

```
conditioned = {2}
condition = True
[i for i in filter(lambda x: condition if x in conditioned else True, [1,2,3,4])]
# [1, 2, 3, 4]

condition = False
[i for i in filter(lambda x: condition if x in conditioned else True, [1,2,3,4])]
[1, 3, 4]
```

Of course you could replace the boolean condition with a function condition(), and use it as a filter instead of the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to output 1 predefined list if condition is true or return the same list plus an element if condition is false (for example). If that's correct you might want something like this:

```
a = [1, 2]

my_condition = 5 > 6

print(a if my_condition else a + [3])
```

Or if you want to define the list in the same line:

```
my_condition = 5 > 6
print([1,2] if my_condition else [1, 2] + [3])
```

In these cases 5 is not greater than 6 so the condition is false so [1, 2, 3] will be output.

Edit: just reading your question it looks like you might want a single value then for true + [one or more values] or for false + [one or more values] so this might be better:

```
a = [1]
print(a + [3] if my_condition else a + [2, 3])
print([1] + [3] if my_condition else [1] + [2, 3])
```

(Just using prints to demonstrate but you can assign this output to a variable using brackets)
I hope this answers your question.